# How to allow only the video recorder of iPhone 3GS to show up using UIImagePickerController class

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiimagepickercontroller, video-capture, iphone-3gs

Using UIImagePicker class I can select the UIImagePickerControllerSource as UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera. This would show up both the options, camera as well as video recoreder.

I want only the video recording option to be available to the user. And as soon as user opens it starts recording without the need to tap record button.

Anyone who knows how is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

set the [mediaTypes](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/mediaTypes) property on the UIImagePickerController.

Comment: yep - that worked setting the media type to kUTTypeMedia. But still the question is not 100% answered. How can I make it possible to record automatically the moment recorder opens up. Do not want user to tap the recording button.

Comment: ah.  no way to do this, I'm quite sure.

Comment: David - Thanks for following up!

Just a super crazy thought - Is it possible UITouch event at a particular (x, y) programmatically?

Comment: so basically you want to simulate a mouse click on the record button?  I don't know, but I don't think I've see any app do it, so probably it's either not possible or not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

in your .h file

```
#define MAX_VIDEO_DURATION 10
@interface VideoCaptureVC_iPhone : UIViewController
<UIActionSheetDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
    UIImagePickerController *picker;
}
```

in your .m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 // Create UIImagePickerController
    picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeMedium;
    picker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString*)kUTTypeMovie];
    picker.videoMaximumDuration = MAX_VIDEO_DURATION;

    // Set the source type to the camera
    [picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];

    // Set ourself as delegate
    [picker setDelegate:self];

    // Always check to see if there is a front facing camera before forcing one on the picker
    if([UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront]){
        [picker setCameraDevice:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront];
    }
    [picker setShowsCameraControls:NO];
[picker takePicture]
}
```